# Next.js Image Fill in Masonry List

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I'm facing issue where normal HTML img tag works just fine inside my Masonry List, but when I'm using Next.js Image Component with layout fill, it doesn't render anything.

**My Styles:**

```
const ImageList = styled('ul', {
    columnCount: 3,
    columnGap: 10,
    display: 'block',
    listStyleType: 'none',
    overflowY: 'auto',
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0
})

const ImageListItem = styled('li', {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'inline-block',
    lineHeight: 0,
    height: 'auto',
    marginBottom: 10
})
```

**HTML Skeleton:**

```
   <ImageList>
            {detailImage.map((image, idx) => {
                return (
                    <ImageListItem key={`_${idx}`}>
                        <Image
                            src={image.src}
                            alt={image.alt}
                            blurDataURL={image.blurDataURL}
                            placeholder={'blur'}
                            layout={'fill'}
                            objectFit={'cover'}
                        />

                        {/* <img
                            src={image.src}
                            style={{
                                width: '100%',
                                height: '100%',
                                objectFit: 'cover'
                            }}
                        /> */}
                    </ImageListItem>
                )
            })}
        </ImageList>
```

**EDIT**
Because I'm getting all images from CMS and have width/height I used the padding-top trick to create box and then I use next/image with object-fit: cover.

Code Example:

```
      <ImageListItem key={`_${idx}`}>
        <Box
          css={{
            display: 'inline-flex',
            pt: `${100 / (image.width! / image.height!)}%`
          }}
        >
          <Box css={{ position: 'absolute', inset: 0, m: 0 }} as={'figure'}>
            <Image
              src={image.src}
              alt={image.alt}
              blurDataURL={image.blurDataURL}
              placeholder={'blur'}
              layout={'fill'}
              objectFit={'cover'}
            />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </ImageListItem>
```

Comment: Could you solve the problem without knowing the image's height and width? @mckvak

Answer (score 0):

When you use `layout='fill'` it's necesary a parent container for each image and this container needs to have `position: relative;`. Maybe it doesn't show anything because its parent elements don't have the width property.

This is the description in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout):

> When fill, the image will stretch both width and height to the
> dimensions of the parent element, provided the parent element is
> relative. This is usually paired with the objectFit property. Ensure
> the parent element has position: relative in their stylesheet.

Comment: Yea, the problem here, is that when I use the width the CSS won't properly work with the list. :). Anyways I edited my question with my solution.